# sharepoint 2013 Get login name programmatically

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

i work with fbamembership provider connect to Aspnetdb using c#
i try to get name of current user in SharePoint 2013 , i use two different methods but a problem has occurred when i use the first one
method 1: **SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName;** but it return null! i don't know why!

method 2: **HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;**
 return *"0#.f|fbamembershipprovider|test@hotmail.com"*

Is there a way to return "test@hotmail.com" only.
Thank You

Comment: Are you running this code in MDS-enabled environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you post your entire code block for method 1? For method 2, you can just opt to perform a `Substring` on the result of your method 2.

Answer (score 0):

For method 2 you can try:

```
string usr= HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
SPClaimProviderManager manager = SPClaimProviderManager.Local;
if (manager != null)
{
    if (SPClaimProviderManager.IsEncodedClaim(usr))
       string result = manager.DecodeClaim(usr).Value;
}
```

[link](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/programmatically-converting-login-name-claim/)

Comment: is not working !
SPClaimProviderManager.IsEncodedClaim(usr) >> return false